# Dynamic connection in Package Part Control Flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

I use `SSIS 2016`. I have created a `Package Part Control Flow` as you can see in this image :

[image]

The perpose of this `Package Part Control Flow` is to have a loop on the all files in one folder and transfer all files to another folder.

I have a `Foreach Loop Container` and a `File System Task`.

[image]

I have created these variable

[image]

Then I have created two `Flat File Connection Manager`:

[image]

Now I need to configure `expressions` for `Connection String` of each `Flat File Connection Manager`.

[image]

But as you can see I don't have access to my variables.

[image]

I need to be able to configure my connection managers inside the `Package Parts Control Flow` and then in package where I use this `Package Parts Control Flow` I will pass the values of variables.

[image]

The way I would like send the value for variables of `Package Parts Control Flow`.

[image]

Can I have an expression on `ConnectionString` of `Flat File Connection Manager` inside the `Package Parts Control Flow` by using the variable?

Comment: I think you need to work with project parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters

Comment: @Hadi : I tag you here because i think may be you know how can we have a dynamic connection manager in Package Part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading multiple articles and users feedbacks.

Unfortunately, you cannot use dynamic connections with package parts.

Control flow Package parts has some limitations, which make it useless in many cases.

**References**

- [Reuse control flow across packages...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/reuse-control-flow-across-packages-by-using-control-flow-package-parts)
- [Package parts in ssis 2016](http://nisalbi.blogspot.com/2016/12/package-parts-in-ssis-2016.html?m=1)
- [control flow package parts in ssis 2016](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2016/10/control-flow-package-parts-in-ssis-2016.html?m=1)
- [My thoughts on ssis 2016 - ssis package parts 1](http://prathy.com/2016/06/my-thoughts-on-ssis-2016-ssis-control-flow-package-parts-1/)
- [My thoughts on ssis 2016 - ssis package parts 2](http://prathy.com/2016/06/my-thoughts-on-ssis-2016-ssis-package-parts-2)

Comment: Thanks @Hadi. What do you think about new feature of SSIS 2016 name Template?

Comment: I didn't checked all ssis 2016 features. Are you talking about package templates?

Comment: There is a new sub folder the same as Package Part in Solution Explorer.

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi concerning package parts take a look at the articles i provided. They will give you a great overview. And they are talking about limitations and benefits

Comment: I had seen the two last and I saw the first three. Thanks. I hop Microsoft in next version improve the Package Part. It can be very usefull

Comment: I agree with that